# subversion installed, cant connect to server

Tags: svn, ubuntu

I am on ubuntu and i have installed svn and whatever else it requires to use it( at least thats what i think from the dozens of tutorials i looked into... )

so i have downloaded Versions subversion client app and when i tried to connect like

svn://user@domain.com

and type my password

i got an error

No repository found in 'svn://user@domain.com/'

i have create my repository called repo inside a folder called /svn but why it wont let me connect?

Comment: Have you started the svnserve daemon?

Comment: try: svn://user@domain.com/svn

Comment: @Jon i get error "No repository found in 'svn://user@domain.com/svn'"

Comment: @khmarbaise yes i have started svnserve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that the part after domain.com/Path gives the absolute path on your machine where a subversion repository has to be created via svnadmin create /Path.

Comment: i have created a folder named /svn and inside it i created a repository via the command above called repo

Comment: Than you need to use domain.com/svn/repo to access that repository instead of domain.com/svn.

Comment: if i try svn co http://hostname/svn/repo repo --username user_name i get message "svn: 'repo' is already a working copy for a different URL" but if i try svn co svn://hostname/repo repo --username user_name i get " No repository found in 'svn://hostname/repo'

Comment: ok i got it working but when i commit it get the following error: Commit failed (details follow):
Authorization failed ( I am using Versions subversion app as stated above)

Comment: Have you configured some kind of passwort/ in your configuration folder?

Comment: i guess you are talking about the username and password that i used to log in into the svn?

Comment: problem was that auth-access was set to read and when i changed it to write all seem to be fine...

Answer (score 0):

It could happen if you manually copy a project to another repository locally and all the .svn directories are still there.

use this on the copied dir

find . -type f -name ".svn" -exec rm -i -f -r  '{}' \;